# How can I run a distributed domain under RedHawk

Tags: redhawksdr

I am trying to create a distributed domain using RedHawk 2.0.1 and cannot find enough information on setting it up in the manual.  I have two related issues. I want to run the domain manager on the same host as the IDE but run one or more components on another node.  I see how to create a new node project but do not see how to specify the network location it should run on.  I can add it to the domain but it simply runs two device managers on the local host. I also do not see details of how to make specific components run on the alternate node.  Does this require manually adding allocation properies?

The related issue is that I would like to use a non-x86 node as the remote node.  I am trying to use an ARM processor and following the instructions in the Sub$100 manual I was able to build and install the runtime system on my ARM, but I find that the GPP device's GPP.spd.xml still has x86 as the processor name while the prf.xml has arm as the required property.

The manual seems to indicate that the binaries for all nodes will be in the sdr of the domain manager, so am I supposed to copy the sdr entries for my arm gpp device and all components back to the sdr of the domain manager host and then they will be deployed back to my arm at domain and waveform launch?

Are there better detailed instructions for distributed domains somewhere that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the last supported version of REDHAWK for the Sub$100 project was 1.10, so we're in uncharted territory. That being said, let's take a stab at it.

The first thing you should do is make sure the /etc/omniORB.cfg file for your Domain Manager looks like this:

```
InitRef = NameService=corbaname::<external IP>:2809
InitRef = EventService=corbaloc::<external IP>10.3.1.245:11169/omniEvents
```

where  should be replaced with your network IP (i.e., not localhost or 127.0.0.1). Restart the CORBA naming and event services with this command:

```
sudo $OSSIEHOME/bin/cleanomni
```

The next step is to configure your ARM device to point to the Domain Manager. Edit the /etc/omniORB.cfg file on the ARM device to match the one from your Domain Manager, even the IP address. Note that you don't have to start the naming and event services on the ARM device.

Now for running the GPP on the ARM device, you will have to create that node on the ARM device, since the Domain doesn't know about that device yet and cannnot access its filesystem. Page 16 of the 1.10 version of the Sub$100 document (http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/redhawksdr/redhawk-doc/1.10.0/REDHAWK-Sub100-Manual-v1.10.0.pdf) has the instructions for installing the GPP.

Note that the newest version of the GPP is actually a C++ Device now, so the second step should be 'cd framework-GPP/cpp' and the third step should be 'git checkout 2.0.1'. Once that's installed, there are still a couple of more issues to take care of. First, run the following command:

```
$SDRROOT/dev/devices/GPP/cpp/devconfig.py --location $SDRROOT/dev/devices/GPP
```

That will configure your GPP to recognize that it is on an ARM platform (as long as your processor is an armv7l processor).

Next, run the following:

```
$SDRROOT/dev/devices/GPP/cpp/create_node.py --domainname <RH Domain Name>
```

That will actually create the DeviceManager profile that will contain your GPP.

The final step involves making sure that the node will be configured correctly. Check out Page 21, Steps 5. Basically you can remove the x86_64 implementation and replace any instances of 'x86' with an 'armv7l'.

As for your question about building your components, yes, you have to build them for the platform of interest and then install them to the Domain Manager SDRROOT. If you have a cross-compiler set up to build your components (and the framework), this will make your life a lot easier. However, if you don't, the workaround is to build the components on your ARM device, then install the XML files and the executable to the Domain. In order to make any components work with your ARM GPP, they will need to have an ARM implementation with a processor name that matches that of your GPP in their SPD.

I know that's a lot and I haven't run through these instructions in a while, so let me know if you have any questions or anything doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

apparently replies are very limited in length so I'll call this an answer.  Thanks for your response.  I have actually tried part of this but will try to see if your information gets me any further.  After writing this question I explored a little further.  I found that the code I had compiled on the ARM and installed still had "x86" and "x86-64" in the domain profile for the device manager and no "armv7l" so I patched the profile  and tried starting the device manager on the ARM manually (after setting the omniORB.cfg to point to the name server on the domain manager host.  It started up fine and said it was trying to connect, and the name server on the domain manager host now had an entry for the ARM device manager but the IDE did not list the additional device manager and if I killed the ARM device manager it said that it was intrupted while waiting to register so I assume that the device manager registered with the name server but never got a reply from the domain manager.  This does not make me hopeful that your steps will work, but I'll give them a try.

Comment: My first instinct for that problem is iptables. Try adding a rule like this to the Domain Manager host: sudo iptables -I INPUT -s <ARM IP> -j ACCEPT

Comment: This is NOT the problem.  I found that and fixed it early.  I have no trouble reaching the remote name server using nameclt (as suggested in the sub$100 doc).  And in fact my remote DevMgr successfully registers with the name server but fails to register with DomMgr

Comment: Well it IS iptables.  iptables is not running on ARM but is running on x86 where the DomMgr is.  I previously added a rule to allow corbaloc but using wireshark I found that DevMgr requests obj ref to DomMgr and then tries to register and iptables rejects that.  I added rule to accept all from local domain and that fixed it.  Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Update. Following more closely the steps in sub$100 document, it appears that $SDRROOT/dev/devices/GPP/cpp/devconfig.py did not edit GPP.spd.xml to put in the correct processor and compiler version but after hand editing these, I was able launch the full domain (domainManager, deviceManager, GPPdevice) on the ARM processor and was able to connect to this running domain from the IDE running on x86.  After exporting and rebuilding my waveform components and editing their domain profiles I was able to use the IDE to launch successfully a very small three component waveform and control it.  So running the entire domain on the ARM works ok.
But I still cannot start the deviceManager on the ARM and have it register with the DomainManager on x86 (after editing the DCD to point to the x86 domain, ie, running a distributed domain with two nodes.  It starts and says it is registering with the domainManager, and it must partly succeed because the devMgr shows up in the NamingService under the domain, but the IDE never shows the new deviceManager in the domain.  And the devMgr never starts the GPPdevice.  If the devMgr is killed it prints "Interrupted waiting to register with DomainManager", so even though it got registered into the Naming Service it appears that the DomainManager never replied to the registration request.

Comment: Interesting. Are the Domain Manager and Device Manager hosts on the same switch/router? Or is there a NAT between them?

Comment: same router, local domain. And since the DevMgr  appears in the NameServer on the Domain host there is obviously connectivity.  If I recall, the DevMgr does NOT register in NS directly but the DomMgr ads it when it registers.  If so registration with DomMgr is partially successful.

Comment: This makes it sound like the DomanManager is attempting to respond to the DeviceManager with a success message and then waits for the ACK. Somehow the Domain's success message is not making it back to the Device Manager. It may be time to break out Wireshark, unless your DeviceManager host has iptables running, although the old Ubuntu version used by the beaglrbone black did not run iptables.